# Automation Test Reporting with testng or Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, testng, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I'm using selenium, testng and jenkins to automate my test cases, run tests and generate reports. I use jenkins dashboard plugin to see the test status and report. Also I use testNG/reportNG to see my test status reports some times. But I need to customize the report more. I feel it difficult to modify the testNG source or dashboard plugin source. Are there any other ideas to generate or customize these test reports? or any other tool to generate/integrate with testNG? Pls help me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TestNG Reporter object to write HTML to the test output.  I use this to insert screenshots, bug links, embed videos etc.

Alternatively, you create a TestNG Reporter listener [(docs)](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html)

This will allow you to create your own reports.

Answer (score 0):

When we execute tests with TestNG, it will generate a default html report with basic information.
 In order to customize it in the way you want like (Start time and Execution time, Browser name, Exception information etc.), you have to implement 'IReporter'  interface to generate a customized report. It has 'generateReport()' method which will be invoked after all the suite has completed its execution and gives the report into the specified output directory.
 For more detail please refer link: 
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-customize-emailable-html-report-example